# How to select the right tags for headers, summaries and dates

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following information: headers, summaries and date.
I tried as follows:

```
    def main(req, num):
        r = req.get(
            website+"/pag/{}/".format(num))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        try:
            data = [(x.select_one("span.timestamp").text, x.findAll("a")[1].text, x.select_one("p.summary story-summary hidden-xs").get_text(strip=True)) for x in soup.select(
                "div.story-content-pull")]
            return data
        except AttributeError:
            print(r.url)
            return False


    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as req:
            fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 10)]
            allin = []
            for f in fs:
                f = f.result()
                if f:
                    allin.extend(f)
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
                allin, columns=["Date", "Title", "Content"])
```

but when I print `data`, it is empty ([]).
It seems that something is wrong with tags. Can you please me help me to find the right ones to include in my code? Thanks

Comment: Did you try debugging where it fails?

Comment: I get "page not found" error with your url.

Comment: I think it is in the tags selection as I am struggling with it. Or with the r.content. I updated the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems in using list comprehension is that it's sometimes difficult to identify problems. So specifically for this issue, take a look at the code below and if it outputs what you are looking for, feel free to convert it back to a list comprehension.

```
stories = soup.select("div.story-content-pull")
data = []
for story in stories:
    data.append(story.select_one('a').text)
    data.append(story.select_one('p').text.strip())
    data.append(story.select_one('time').text)
data
```

Output:

```
['A Pedara diminuisce il numero dei positivi al Covid-19',
 'Lo rende noto il Sindaco, invitando la popolazione alla massima prudenza',
 'ieri mattina, 09:12',
 'Sono 2215 i tamponi eseguiti nella prima delle tre giornate di test rapidi sul Coronavirus',
 'Sono stati 614 i tamponi somministrati a Catania, riscontrando 14 tamponi positivi',
 "l'altro ieri, 19:16",
```

etc.

Edit:

To get it all into a 3 columns dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ["header", "summaries", "date"] #apologies; my Italian is not what it should be...
data = []
for story in stories:
    row = []
    row.append(story.select_one('a').text)
    row.append(story.select_one('p').text.strip())
    row.append(story.select_one('time').text)
    data.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
      header                                           summaries                      date
0   A Pedara diminuisce il numero dei positivi al ...   Lo rende noto il Sindaco, invitando la popolaz...   ieri mattina, 09:12
1   Sono 2215 i tamponi eseguiti nella prima delle...   Sono stati 614 i tamponi somministrati a Catan...   l'altro ieri, 19:16
2   A Tremestieri continua la campagna elettorale:...   Nei Comuni già sciolti per infiltrazioni mafio...   l'altro ieri, 18:04
```

etc.

Comment: Hi Jack, can you please tell me how I should pass that data into the three columns? I got the error : ValueError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 315 columns.  I passed data and the individual field, but both returned me the same error. Many thanks

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but I would like to ask you a quick question: do you think the data I am scraping are from the first page? I checked the results but I got different, 'strange' results. Just wanted to confirm if something does not work in my code (second part), in order to open a new question on this (since I have not found any solution yet to scrape data across pages). Many thanks

Comment: @LucaDiMauro If by "second part" you mean the part that starts with `with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:`, I'm afraid I can't help, since I don't know anything about `ThreadPoolExecutor()`. You should probably post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I just wanted to be sure that it was not me and that the code was not working properly ;) I will open a new question on this. Thanks a lot for all your help